# I can access postgres database on Rails even with a wrong password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm able to connect to my local Postgres database, even with a wrong password. Here is how I created a role and a database (I'm on Mac OSX with Postgres 9.3):

```
psql postgres

CREATE ROLE role_name WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'role_password' NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN;

CREATE DATABASE db_name OWNER role_name;

\q
```

So, when I configure my `database.yml` file on Rails, using the following:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db_name
  username: role_name
  password: this_is_a_wrong_password_ha_ha
```

and starting the server (`rails s`), everything works fine: I can create tables with migrations and create/read/update/delete data in it.

I can even do that without giving a role and/or a password.

How can I block access to a database if the role name and role password are not correct? Where I'm wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is default settings for your `/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf`. It is allow access to DB for any local connections:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Comment: Yes @maxd, you're right. my pg_hba.conf is identical to your answer. How can I prevent this? (I mean only a particular user for a particular database)

Comment: Just [adjust this config](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and restart Postgres.

Comment: reload is good enough, you don't have to restart the database for this type of change.